# Reinitialize redux form state from saved state

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am creating a dynamic form where users can add fields and then later someone else can add data to them.

i have successfully saved the whole form state into a database,

now i need to load the whole state into the form[image: form state]

> i am not trying to load the initial values from the state. the from does not have any fields etc. i am trying to load all those from the database

but i am unable to figure out how.
can any one help me

Comment: You need to dynamically render the Fields based on the data

Comment: is there no way to directly mount the form state into the reducer?